# Multi-User Database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, nhibernate

My experience with databases is limited so I am not sure of the best way to ask this question, so I am going to break it down as simply as possible. I've built an **ASP.net** application with a **mySQL** database using **NHibernate** that has multiple users that can log in and all work on the same table (let's say of forum posts). So we have our **users table** and our **food table**.

Now I am looking for the best way to split these users into groups, very much like different companies. So The users from the same "company" can log on and see all there other company users and edit/create posts view-able by said "company".

I am looking for the most scalable (fastest with 1000's of companies) way to do this. Should I

**1:** Have a universal table for users and posts with a foreign key? So everything is stored on the same SQL table but their view of this table is restricted by the company ID. I see this being the easiest one to build, but will 1000's of companies accessing the same table with this be slow/problematic?

**2:** Create a new posts table for every company? So every user from a company accesses their own table of posts. To scale up would this be more efficient/faster if there were thousands of companies?

A quick explanation of the best method would be really appreciated. But also pointing me to documentation/resources would be amazing! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest **option 1**.
You should create **company table** with **companyID** as primary key. Use **companyID** as foreign key in **users table** and **food table**.
This is regular approach and works well in most of the cases.

It would be very complicated to maintain 1000's of tables in the application.
Users and food table will be already indexed by company ID so the filtering will be very fast.